# Prove, that random variables are independent iff $P(X = i;Y = j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j)$

Tags: probability

Prove, if that random variables are independent and whose values are from $\mathbb{N}$  then $P(X = i;Y = j)=P(X=i)P(Y=j)$ using only this definition:

> Random variables $X$,$Y$ are independent iff $P(X \leq i;Y \leq j)=P(X \leq i)P(Y\leq j)$

Right of the bat I have no idea how to even approach this. Can anybody give me a hint where to start? I'm having a really hard time trying to justify any expansions of the term on the left side of the equation.

I tried expanding the right side...

$P(X=i)P(Y=j)= \\ (P(X \le i)-P(X \le i-1))(P(Y \le j)-P(Y \le j-1)= \\ P(X \le i)P(Y \le j)-P(X \le i-1)P(Y \le j)-P(X \le i)P(Y \le j-1)+P(X \le i-1)P(Y \le j-1)= \\ P(X \le i;Y \le j)-P(X \le i-1;Y \le j)-P(X \le i;Y \le j-1)+P(X \le i-1;Y \le j-1) \\  $

... to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems you're almost there.
As a note, I prefer writing $P(X < i)$ instead of $P(X \leq i - 1)$.  It doesn't change anything since you work on integers, but does a better job in the general discrete case.

So anyway, one way would be to notice that $P(X \leq i; Y \leq j) = P(X = i; Y \leq j) + P(X < i; Y \leq j)$.

So in your last line, the $P(X \leq i; Y \leq j) - P(X < i; Y \leq j)$ terms become $P(X = i; Y \leq j)$.

And you could rewrite the whole last line as

$P(X = i; Y \leq j) - (P(X \leq i; Y < j) - P(X < i; Y < j))$

For your own sake, I don't want to give the complete answer, but you can apply the same reasoning on the two last terms in parenthesis.
And then reapply one last time to get your answer.